# shell script: single quote in execute

Tags: shell, escaping, shellexecute

I'm having trouble using a single quote in a command executed from within a shell script.
In my script I execute an rdesktop command that should have -u '' (<- 2 single quotes) as a parameter.
However, no matter how I try to escape the quotes it is not passed correctly.

If I just echo $command the output is fine, if I execute it weird output is created

This is the part of the script that doesn't work:

```
command="rdesktop -u "\'\'" $server"
`$command`
```

I also tried executing it directly:

```
`rdesktop -u "\'\'" $server`
```

I would appreciate any help since I read quite a few tutorials on escaping characters in shell scripts and didn't find the solution..

EDIT:

interestingly enough, if I just use

```
command=rdesktop -u '' $server
```

and echo it, the output is fine
however, if I execute it with

```
$command
```

it fails...

Comment: how about `rdesktop -u "''" $server` ?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on superusers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shell is bash or ksh or zsh, it's much safer and easier to build up a command with an array rather than a string:

```
command=( rdesktop -u '' $server )
```

and execute it like this

```
"${command[@]}"
```

I can't imagine the remote server needs to see a username named literally `''` (i.e. 2 single quotes) -- it probably wants just an empty string.

Comment: @derFunk, no, only if you want to capture the output. When you do this  `echo foo`, you see foo; when you do this `$(echo foo)`, you send the result of the command substitution to the shell to **execute** as a command -- you will get `foo: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

First, if you type

```
`rdesktop something`
```

then that means to invoke `rdesktop`, take the output, and run that output as a command. To “execute it directly,” simply type

```
rdesktop something
```

Now for the quotes. If you execute

```
rdesktop -u '' $server
```

then `rdesktop` will not see the quotes. They are removed as part of the shell parsing the command. To get `rdesktop` to see an argument `''`, use

```
rdesktop -u "''" $server
```

There's no need really to add any further escaping, since single quotes are not special inside a double-quoted string.

**EDIT:** When all you want to do with the command in a variable is to execute it, note that this stripping of quotes only happens once:

```
cmd="rdesktop -u '' $server"
$cmd
```

Comment: Hm, unfortunately this doesn't work for me, if I use
`cmd="rdesktop -u \"''\" $server"`
it passes "''" as the parameter, not ''

Comment: Edited. Although I still don't think your remote username actually consists of two single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `rdesktop -u '' $server`, you are invoking rdesktop with 3 arguments, the second of which is the empty string.  It's not clear to me why you are trying to invoke it in backticks, but you can get what you want using your first definition of command and:

```
eval $command
```

Note that if you do not completely control the contents of `$server`, then this is a big security risk.  (For example, if server is the string `; cmd`, then invoking eval will execute `cmd`)